# MVC design - Can I have domain model validation in the Controller class?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

The following is just an exmaple for context not the actual implementation. Using Spring MVC, I have the following **Model** which has validation based on annotations.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
   @Id private int id;
   @NotNull private String name;
}
```

And the following **DTO** used to map the data received in the request's body in the **Controller's** `createNewCustomer` function.

```
public class CustmerDTO{
    private String name;
}
```

In my **Controller** I am using the `modelMapper` to convert the `customerDTO` to a new domain model **Customer** object. Based on the *@NotNull* annotation, if the **name** property of the recieved object (`customerDTO`) is empty the *ConstraintViolationException* is thrown.

```
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired private CustomerService customerService;
    @Autowired private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @PostMapping(value = "/customer")
    public Customer createNewCustomer (@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        try {
            Customer newCustomer = modelMapper.map(customerDTO, Customer.class);
            return customerService.saveCustomer(newCustomer);
        }
        catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            throw new CustomerMissingInformation();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here I handle validation for the **Customer** in the **Controller**, which by definition is not a good habit, as **Controllers** in **MVC** are part of the **presentation layer**, and should have no clue about how to perform data validation, also I want to keep my controllers as light as possible.

Can I keep this design or is there any good approach to move my validation in the **Service** layer while keeping validation annotations and also allowing the **Controller** to be able to receive representation objects(`DTOs`) and convert them to domain models?

Comment: You could create an extra class that validates your constraints as shown [here](https://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator)... There is even an interface for validators: `org.springframework.validation.Validator;`

Comment: Try hibernate validator refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_hibernate_validator.htm. You can define validation in model class itself.

Comment: Why don't you validate in the service class instead, that's where this logic should be, the controllers should just control data flow in and out of the application.

Comment: @AmanJ because having validation annotations over the Customer properties(eg. NotNull over the name property), when I map in the Controller  the DTO recieved to a new Customer object (customerDTO -> newCustomer), if the title is missing in the DTO the error is thrown

Comment: @AdrianBrad Recieve the CustomerDTO in the service class and do the conversion there

Comment: @AmanJ service is in the business logic layer and should not have any idea about the objects used for representation. Eg. I can have multiple representations for the Customer like CustomerDTO, CustomerAndOrdersDTO and my service only accepts Customer as the input for it's CRUD functions. So, those representations should be converted to domain models(Customer) in the Controller and then sent to the service. We also can have different Controllers for different Views but they all should use the same service layer.

Comment: You don't need the extra DTO class, Just use the entity for this reason. Entities only have a single, data storage responsibility without any business logic.

Comment: You can use an exception handler AOP aspect.

Comment: You have to use the `@valid` Spring annotation on controller method parameters to perform the validation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking more into this, I came to the following conclusion. Validation for persisting an object should happen as soon as possible and at property level, as you don't want your persistence layer or any mappers that you might be using deal with **null** when it is not expected. Everything that goes past **property validation**, shall be approached from a [contextual validation perspective](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContextualValidation.html), and be passed to methods that hold logic for a given context.

> Is this order valid to be filled, is this customer valid to check in to the hotel. So rather than have methods like isValid have methods like isValidForCheckIn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [SmartConstraints](https://github.com/jruillier/smartconstraints), an annotation processor that allows you to reuse validation annotations from your entities to your DTOs without rewriting them. I think it could solve your problem gracefully.

After enabling SmartConstraints, just annotate your DTO like :

```java
public class CustmerDTO{
    @ValidName
    private String name;
}
```

And enable validation at controller level with (at class level) :

```java
@Validated
```

Comment: I notice that you've posted 3 answers recently that promote one of your libraries. While a few answers that do so are permitted, I would suggest slowing down with these answers. If a large-ish proportion of your answers promote your own content that can be considered as spam on this site.